# Issue launching application on Phone (Galaxy Ace S5830i) from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

As i've written in title, i can't test my applications on my real phone through eclipse. 
Before writing this question, i've read a lot of discussion here on stackoverflow so i try to be clear:
I've a Galaxy Ace S5830i, and i want to test my apps on that phone instead of the emulator, so :

1. I've enabled the "**USB Debugging**" option on my Phone;
2. I've installed all necessary **drivers** of the phone on my PC;
3. I can see on "device management" my phone:

I can see my phone on the "Device" section of **DDMS**, but when i press run and a window ask me to choose the device, my phone isn't here, i have ONLY the emulator...
Why?

Comment: Try resetting the ADB, go to the devices tab, click the triangle for more options and you'll see a reset adb option.

Comment: This happens to me all the time with my Galaxy Nexus because the usb cable does not connect well to the phone. After you press Run As > Android Application, if you don't see your device in the promp window then unplug/reconnect the usb cable, see if it comes up.

Comment: After resetting the ADB it works well. Thank you *Tim Kranen*!